# Comparing words in strings in two columns

Tags: vba, excel, comparison

I want to compare the cells (strings) of two columns and check if:

- There is some cells with "two" matching words
- There is some cells which begin by the same word

My code returns an error.

```vb
Sub Find_Matches()
    Dim CompareRange As Variant, x As Variant, y As Variant, mot As Variant, mot2 As Variant, compt As Variant, element As Variant, element2 As Variant

    compt = 0   'counter for number of matching words
    Set CompareRange = Range("C1:C1796")   'first column

    For Each x In Selection   'second column
        For Each y In CompareRange

            mot = Split(x, " ")   'converting strings to words arrays
            mot2 = Split(y, " ")

            For Each element In mot
                For Each element2 In mot2
                    If element = element2 Then compt = compt + 1   'matching words counter incrementation
                Next element2
            Next element

            If compt >= 2 Or mot(0) = mot2(0) Then ....   'if/or then do something
            compt = 0

        Next y
    Next x
End Sub
```

When I debug, the highlighted text is: `If compt >= 2 Or mot(0) = mot2(0)`.

The error translated since I'm using a French version:

> "Execution error '9': The index doesn't belong to the selection"

**UPDATE1:** I have the same error even if the cells are not empty on same line:

```vb
For Each x In Selection
    For Each y In CompareRange
        
        If CStr(x) & CStr(y) <> vbNullString Then
             mot = Split(x, " ")
             mot2 = Split(y, " ")
        Else: MsgBox "empty cell!"
        End If
        
        For Each element In mot
            For Each element2 In mot2
                If element = element2 Then compt = compt + 1
            Next element2
        Next element
        If compt >= 2 Or mot(0) = mot2(0) Then x.Offset(0, 1) = x
        compt = 0
    Next y
Next x
```

Comment: if you have an empty cell in any of those ranges you will get a subscript out of range error referencing mot(0) or mot2(0)

Comment: @CRondao The error translated since I'm using a french version is: "Execution error '9': The index doesn't belong to the selection".

Comment: And the error is in which line?

Comment: @CRondao "If compt >= 2 Or mot(0) = mot2(0)"

Comment: Yeah thats what I thought it is a Subscript out of range. One of your range contains an empty cell, make sure you don have any empty cells.

Comment: Can you check `CStr(x) & CStr(y) <> vbNullString` before Splitting `x` and `y`? If a cell is empty `Split` returns run-time error 9.

Comment: @CRondao I second that - was writing my comment when yours popped up!

Comment: @CRondao Same problem even if the cells are not empty! Check my update please.

Comment: Well I tried your code and works, maybe you have cells with more than one space between words...

Comment: @CRondao That is very probable! I wonder how to solve this!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this, and hope there is no more than 2 consecutive spaces :), write it before the splits

```
x = Trim(Replace(x, "  ", " "))
y = Trim(Replace(y, "  ", " "))
```

Use this function to remove unneeded spaces:

```
Function RemoveSpaces(ByVal s As String) As String
Dim a As Integer, b As Integer
s = Trim(s)
Do
 a = Len(s)
 s = Replace(s, "  ", " ")
 b = Len(s)
Loop Until a = b
RemoveSpaces = s
End Function
```

Now in your sub use x = RemoveSpaces(x)

Comment: Unfornatuly there is more than 2 consecutive spaces... Thank you by the way.